# PHP crashes when I run a script

Tags: php, macos, mamp, homebrew

Whenever I try to run a PHP script on the command line, it crashes imediately. I get this errors:

```
Xdebug requires Zend Engine API version 220090626.
The Zend Engine API version 220100525 which is installed, is newer.
Contact Derick Rethans at http://xdebug.org/docs/faq#api for a later version of Xdebug.


Warning: PHP Startup: imap: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20090626
PHP    compiled with module API=20100525
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0

Warning: PHP Startup: gettext: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20090626
PHP    compiled with module API=20100525
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0

Warning: PHP Startup: mcrypt: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20090626
PHP    compiled with module API=20100525
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0

Warning: PHP Startup: yaz: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20090626
PHP    compiled with module API=20100525
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0

Warning: PHP Startup: pgsql: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20090626
PHP    compiled with module API=20100525
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0

Warning: PHP Startup: pdo_pgsql: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20090626
PHP    compiled with module API=20100525
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0

Warning: PHP Startup: pdo_mysql: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20090626
PHP    compiled with module API=20100525
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0

Warning: PHP Startup: uploadprogress: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20090626
PHP    compiled with module API=20100525
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0

Fatal error: Directive 'allow_call_time_pass_reference' is no longer available in PHP in Unknown on line 0
```

This is the PHP part of my .profile.

```
# make sure we use MAMP version of php and other binaries
export PATH=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.14/bin/:$PATH

# make sure we use MAMP version of mysql and other binaries
export PATH=/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin:$PATH

# make sure we are using the same php.ini as MAMP PRO
export PHPRC='/Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/conf/php.ini'

# make brew doctor happy
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
export PATH=/usr/local/sbin:$PATH
```

This has been working for months without problems. But leatly I updated to Maverik and had to update XCode and lots of homebrew stuff. After all I thought all my PHP stuff is comming from MAMP and should not be related to this.

Any ideas?

Comment: All these modules listed were not compiled for this PHP.

Comment: You gotta enable/install all those modules first.

Comment: How you enable those modules depends on what system you are running on.

Comment: I addded more information about my set-up. Is this the missing information?